# jQuery different click() function for an element within another element with a click()

Tags: jquery

on my website I have a sidebar panel, which has two tabs that when clicked switch the content beneath. on the `<li>` for these tabs I have a jQuery `click()` event to switch the tabs. Please see the screengrab for what I mean

[alt text http://cci.epiphanydev2.co.uk/Home_1281538687319.png](http://cci.epiphanydev2.co.uk/Home_1281538687319.png)

This was all working fine until our designer wanted the RSS feed link within the `<li>`, so now when I click on the RSS feed icon, it is being overridden by the `click()` function on the `<li>`

My jQuery so far for the tabs is as follows:

```
//NEWS PANEL
$("div.switch-tab div.listing-box").hide();
$(".news ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();
$("div.switch-tab div.listing-box:first").show();

$(".news ul.tabs li").click(function() {
    $(".news ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("div.switch-tab div.listing-box").hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    $(activeTab).fadeIn();
    return false;
});
// ATTEMPT TO OVERRIDE
$(".news ul.tabs li a.feed").click(function() {
    return true;
});
//END NEWS PANEL
```

Any idea how I can get round this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

event.stopPropagation() is what you're looking for: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

You'll need to pass in the event and then put event.stopPropagation() in the click function of your feed links.  So do something like this:

```
// ATTEMPT TO OVERRIDE
$(".news ul.tabs li a.feed").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    return true;
});
```

This will stop the click event from bubbling up to containing parents, in your case, the tab `<li>`

See a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/kjdeG/

Answer (score 2):

Use event.stopPropagation()